# Generic functions and mapped types: why do some of these functions have trouble narrowing types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to understand why some of my generic functions that deal with mapped types give me type errors and others do not.

Given the following:

```
type Types = {
    num: number
    str: string
}

const funcs: {[K in keyof Types]: () => Types[K]} = {
    num: () => 7,
    str: () => "hi"
}

const objects: {[K in keyof Types]: {value: Types[K]}} = {
    num: {
        value: 7
    },
    str: {
        value: "hi"
    }
}

const values: {[K in keyof Types]: Types[K]} = { // I know this type is equivalent to just `Types`, but leaving it like this to have the same shape as the type for funcs
    num: 7,
    str: "hi"
}
```

Why is this first function ok, but the other two give me type errors?

```
export const getValue1_Success = <K extends keyof Types>(key: K): Types[K] => {
    const value = values[key] // Type: { num: number; str: string; }[K]
    return value // This is fine
}

export const getObjectValue1_Error = <K extends keyof Types>(key: K): Types[K] => {
    const obj = objects[key] // Type: { num: { value: number; }; str: { value: string; }; }[K]
    const value = obj.value // Type: string | number
    return value
    // Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'Types[K]'.
    //   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Types[K]'.
    //     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
}

export const getFuncValue1_Error = <K extends keyof Types>(key: K): Types[K] => {
    const func = funcs[key] // Type: { num: () => number; str: () => string; }[K]
    const value = func() // Type: string | number
    return value
    // Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'Types[K]'.
    //   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Types[K]'.
    //     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
}
```

It seems like in the first function, it's able to resolve `values[key]` to the type `{ num: number; str: string; }[K]`, which it is able to assign to `Types[K]`. This makes sense to me.

But in the second and third functions, it seems to lose the specificity and end up with `string | number` for the value, which it can't assign to `Types[K]`. The error message also make makes it sound like it's treating `Types[K]` as `never`, which I don't understand. It's the same function signature as the first function, so why is that a problem here?

Interestingly, when I change the return type to direct `typeof` references to the objects we're reading from, the Object example starts to work, but the Function example still doesn't:

```
export const getValue2_Success = <K extends keyof Types>(key: K): typeof values[K] => {
    return values[key] // Type: { num: number; str: string; }[K]
}

export const getObjectValue2_Success = <K extends keyof Types>(key: K): typeof objects[K]["value"] => {
    return objects[key].value // Type: string | number
}

export const getFuncValue2_Error = <K extends keyof Types>(key: K): ReturnType<typeof funcs[K]> => {
    return funcs[key]() // Type: string | number
    // Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<{ num: () => number; str: () => string; }[K]>'.
    //   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<{ num: () => number; str: () => string; }[K]>'.ts(2322)
}
```

I find it interesting that in the above `getObjectValue2_Success`, it's saying the type of `objects[key].value` is `string | number`, but when it's called given a string literal, it's able to narrow the return type down correctly:

```
const num = getObjectValue2_Success("num") // Type: number
const str = getObjectValue2_Success("str") // Type: string
```

Now, if I remove the explicit return type from the function signature, all functions compile just fine:

```
// This return type is inferred as:
//      {
//          num: number;
//          str: string;
//      }[K]
export const getValue3_Success = <K extends keyof Types>(key: K) => {
    return values[key] // This is fine
}

// This return type is inferred as:
//      string | number
export const getObjectValue3_Success = <K extends keyof Types>(key: K) => {
    return objects[key].value
}

// This return type is inferred as:
//      string | number
export const getFuncValue3_Success = <K extends keyof Types>(key: K) => {
    return funcs[key]()
}
```

However, the second and third functions lacks the specificity of its return type:

```
const numValue = getValue3_Success("num") // Type: number, as expected
const strValue = getValue3_Success("str") // Type: string, as expected

const numObjValue = getObjectValue3_Success("num") // Type: string | number, I wish this could be just number
const strObjValue = getObjectValue3_Success("str") // Type: string | number, I wish this could be just string

const numFuncValue = getFuncValue3_Success("num") // Type: string | number, I wish this could be just number
const strFuncValue = getFuncValue3_Success("str") // Type: string | number, I wish this could be just string

const randomKey = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "num" : "str"
const randomValue = getValue3_Success(randomKey) // Type: string | number, as expected
const randomObjectValue = getObjectValue3_Success(randomKey) // Type: number | string, as expected
const randomFuncValue = getFuncValue3_Success(randomKey) // Type: number | string, as expected
```

I would love any help with understanding why this is happening, and any suggestions as to how to make the original `getObjectValue...` and `getFuncValue...` functions work, so that they can return the narrow type that corresponds to the key it is passed, just like the `getValue...` function does.

Thanks!

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEkHIFtQFwE4E8CWA7A5vA9qArmgCYCmCAznAIZGgDuAFkqGdtMaNgGajRMbFpSKAMahOBYXBTY0ZePUpxQJSgBs6KOPR6UADruKF4SA3IwoAbuzbGDoUgmzlQ1I9i2k5hXGncA6AFgAKGCQUABxSwF5dk5sVVVsWnQMAC5g4LgTdgAVbLkAXlAAb2DQctA0PGhUyuqAI1IyiooEWtaU4IBfDKDhGQoxCTJa4oBtAGlQdFAAa2IkLlA80wBdWoAKAEpQAoA%20ZfzJ1a7dkubyqprQbd2DgHYAGgvmRE2d-dAAInoUL%207ev1ZEpsPUAFbESQjEqTaZoOYLJYrYhkdYlCxqPDEWrIsjHLqnIqlIIVOrXYmk0kY1RY2r3F5dZ4klpvc7Mymgam076-f7s0A9IKC4JAwZclGjWEzeaLbi4tG4-FnYqgMLgOa%20WjyFByLJ2HX2ACOeEsagESjguDBeEGAANcbbHqB6nglKpiJQLClpm6UPNtbrcAorDFmJQbGQFHZKLr6Ow9bEnEM0MIyC8rnSmaTWrUfn8ASEgmEAOqMaaxg2cFDkJTiFNSGQcWZOl0WuMcDwIeC0XDmEM2BP2BCOcgAfl6xAAHronEpRUp%20HAAGqY4gARgA%20gBlPDCYQowqgAA8UyncAEhDkMqR%20T2GxltQmWxxRwmqzubNJ885q7O4rxMrvmEyKjGStRXI0CAANyvG0sEpDBXTHC8CDEHAeAIPC4qqmAOS-HIlboMQBbBFOM4IHOAwLmhADy4KQsuq6bgAosOSZFCe9iTueRBXoicq3veCyPs%20hymMcH4UhU36gmCZyyQxAELEBuHZKBGYlD%20NLYmSkGITBOaaeK7SIAhAqIch-LfthRSyX42HAWp8GYKAAA%20ulNPyqHoZhWlYi8jl2JAHQue5EGkJA5aVO4LhkGQKAYGglD1O6OC2OwkCKm%20kCBPyYTlMioDBaZmCRQavhKDG8WJclqWWulRVZasOUBWApKFcVCApGVcgVbF1VJSl8a4IOkCCFYCA5XAZAbAATAAzLNs1bCRQRkbOoDfouABiEgrtpLFsV2HGntxF58bKYkoneD6gE%20L7iW%20kkvN%20daiEUb1KUgKlXep1TvB%204XQbBAOfCFGAWW%20L1UX57AfRItyBTp4NuR5CAoWhGFYaurVXUVKNhQ0EVRX1VUJYNdUjdkjWvs1uWkvleOdd1JMxWTNVDWlo1NS1eVtRUHXgz10WVXF5O1cNDVjcQE1TTNC1LStQq9GqShkMQxDQHIqh%20uwMweGI1aDG9DZoE6mjBS4nP1ahLCqCGtr-mMgG2lz7aDraKoaUDBmsuDkOrI6dC-MI2iaFFEtpez8L1fatO2n4yz4To8xyOrsiS2wuWhGAABCrpwqG6tAkYrjaggRgm9Isjm2rGta2liTq0XBjCCgVZt1kLg0Be%20C6BoWigLaBNo67cRdgb4pOgwIhh3O1CQKLA1pXHj2B4neHsA4SZsHFlD8C4qgsCn1iUKnPrMNgBBGDr-oW7qqGKN6q8oscrsxkP42kEHM%20hxAygyEXvgIgngqBEETuAOAlsDZkHDLECQptmDix8uwD%20Bsqw1mTJIauTpj4MCYAaLQigXCgF0I4IasA4yoXHIWNUaBzy2ykJgVQSBp5xnhOqUO1AD4G28ljBq9VCDVgYkPBMXBXaoU4KQAQ%205AyhgUlCOgxBICoVAI-IRLlOCOGgE6A2dEISSC4uGXQqUKCUAonInsCBmzOgLgbXa9Zq5GOgCY9gFAUAJAASiNAi90iFnWhRTaMNFz7SxLNbcu5ZGHk4mec6CJLq4husJO6okxHcCdk9T4Ulyh8N8k7QCOFfqaW9kTYGhl-YCkssKNa04NpbVovRSQoTiDhJ3HuA8ZwYlnV4vEm8pgklIBErUNJHBGnTWOGML44ovjviyRjHy8IFHjMAvZX8SMTJdVCmjVaATKLAlADtPaq5wmsRHJ006PFLy9IEv0oSgyUm1AAEqY0wsiI8IzPrHAOHMryLz4SfMAojVSBgNnekJtASCuNBYlSwOCyCwtSZiw5pTKWzyFlvK9v9G4HwDg%20xBtij8FSkJvj2LzBm-NoWbIwAitmSKKaS1GmirGGKwIEs%20HiwytwwYwoDqSvw005qLWWqtNUhsaDh3QAwlETCsBEKUPrdsyVsAO0XPohizTWmRIPEHe%20YZUAuQNoOJYtollfVWKs7SrsDTDxhajIGQdWzB2iLq4Qah3RGD7NESgzksA6wYWoWultI71SSmxLUvC-kNW8LQeE-RhwMRYX4kUMMrhnFVWMjVET2lxQ2F8K4XwdjrO2X0GGrQ00NIMYxbSmrs0zS%20K0AthSQI%20pVmAAAckkc23B1SoWgMq%20M7YyI607moyNg4tGsFDFXRsA1FAYWIE6N1WDTZyH6C4jx7BrTGyIkmosuFk65JjtTA06ApHxtLiMHOHJiSMw5Kyn2V673lHKTyx9pJiWrFIrUwJ9Sq1YnmlmqJ5yuKXIun066dyRLPV%20Qs2GZqm3J0IoIEV%206DSHoaietAZ7UIXr8be59tq4WeV2UE-Z6bK3NIA20oDJ0QNxOvDciDt0nzQdJOh01ztlIWv8srWhqG5DocHJh7DhhYp4f5iyKldrSlfvInswYhyUyUcAx02jsSekMaumQAZUGflscjQC5S2wUOgAABJJBlqQXR7Zi4yFLjQLQ1ZK4IOrtrSgwhZixjca3duIhNBMCWJoATY61KAhTdUZp5a-3ECo1qnNebqiNqLUDRdcgyIMUMMm-ZrRItFBCauWLtbc0NsLcC5GMLUtcVbueQgYX9lXH0blg5Fb1UFZU-F-NpWikjxS--ZIkYAxBLwKoIwjRQBbqUEDLLgxWiNd-HllrTS2vUYPMVxASWyugq2b19U-XtCOdXVfEbzpN02jVjCurgwrgOOEE1xTt3ltxbrZ1ptTkeulKdLtnU%203k79GG6N07V2ZMluy4gG7d20Lg8e0V%20t62uvNvexCqzfXvuDb%208dsbE2W2Fm-AgVwrAJgLDOAAWUUPQPweOiCsFuAcAADH4AArKAUc3x82gFzA26bShKfeGgBD6LhWokbB5wThY8O3uEbRpV9LkhMsg8GCL6AaqlvaSi8rgX7WZqK8J0gcXIK0ao3BtL6cGXavy%205-j6AUPVcLbgNb-9mvheW513rnSQNDcVdilV03ra%20tHZvv27uTA4yqH7skQe19QGuG9PgwbBoowGDQCkRdNBqBMDIHgDA-B3EDC9-VegSQ0rQDPgO9gTgEroDUEPcjrXtJ%20Hr%20-Ggtp7vNPr34MeLnc9WJscfOVMQmCuvhIJ9sobHDhupn3uNtsZw9PqgbGUF8DS6CqoYJ0WPb6l%20r2hVvDfl1OO8CibOe6k7UE8wAQiAA)

Comment: Great example. I'm still learning Typescript so forgive me if I'm incorrect. I believe its because Typescript can't extrapolate the return types without specifying the exact working type. For example for your second function, `{[K in keyof Types]: {value: Types[K]}}["value"]` or equivalent `typeof objects[K]["value"]` would work. I'm not sure why there is such a limitation other than for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

In order to better understand why `Types[K]` is resolved to `never`, consider this example:

```js
type Types = {
    num: { n: number }
    str: { s: string }
}

const funcs: { [K in keyof Types]: () => Types[K] } = {
    num: () => ({ n: 7 }),
    str: () => ({ s: "hi" })
}

const objects: { [K in keyof Types]: { value: Types[K] } } = {
    num: {
        value: { n: 7 }
    },
    str: {
        value: { s: "hi" }
    }
}

const values: { [K in keyof Types]: Types[K] } = {
    num: { n: 7 },
    str: { s: "hi" }
}

export const getValue1_Success = <K extends keyof Types>(key: K): Types[K] => {
    const value = values[key] // Type: { num: number; str: string; }[K]
    return value // This is fine
}

export const getObjectValue1_Error = <K extends keyof Types>(key: K): Types[K] => {
    const obj = objects[key] // Type: { num: { value: number; }; str: { value: string; }; }[K]
    const value = obj.value// Type: string | number
    return value // error

}

export const getFuncValue1_Error = <K extends keyof Types>(key: K): Types[K] => {
    const func = funcs[key] // Type: { num: () => number; str: () => string; }[K]
    const value = func() // Type: string | number
    return value // error
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20210902#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEGcoF4oG8BQVtQHYFcBbALjyICMIAnLHBYK0+qgS1wHMMBfDDAej5R2EYFACGUfLhYB7XFBkAzcQBsVUAG5iV+RBlCQoANW26EAHhgA+FLADaAawgglsALoZMOKAKjM27FAAPmSElDTeBtAwiKKoJjqIlvAIVty8vsBiTuKS0nLiuAAmUITZiHgSbMDUCBAAxsCy8gC0pdTCSCzA+vBQAKr5uDAyAJK4NVR1jc3m-TaoABT9UBAAHjXFSGK4IFAA-FCLDqT9AJQoNhoyLCWkuBAa1Bfrm0VIi7TYJ1BsitRQUYYC7IK43IpfA6AyH3R7UADcvCiUAAgmoZAB3CBFADKWRqFmsti8ODsAAUqDIwL95E4XMoYG5SAAlBoyKhFcwUqkAGnQmlMEFIMHJlLAbigXDSPBJ2F89RkagaTQKrm06nVmOxfnxFQx3QAFqsNlQJAaWOwDaIVHD1GAxdRQJDkTF6LY0SotbjdYSUtKkX0APLkABWysJCwGQxG40m0xVuHMCTM5g9XrxYgJlisOc8kN8mqxJXomYgzr6rriUGDYcavsgqXS-EEgaeVE9YiKASginZUHq+CorG1iikMwKLRsOHMAGljW8kHTXDWrMdnKQZyCrDJQ45nG4AHRaRK9Qyt6gdrsccw1+cQLZQVkKjnmfwcPloAWJUhSBy4THyFKCyQgAZEcs53g+S7KCua4gBuW7VruM5uHYADkx66GhbhnLw6xgOyogKrgbr6sABq3qg5iQjAkHvLAKQ8pCt6vPe9E1uG2ZQGBT7spyb7sB+X66KQyZJHADY2FKTHeKuO4hqQNZnMQzFtpeAQ3qGCw2BBrFQc4y5aXBCGXJC3jyXuICHphZYYMRbrCMAHGNGJthkRRoaLLKoSkN53g2aQADskJcDJdAML5Zk4AFUAAETmrFIXcLhdlyG6VCIPgKjAAAjLYjnOcAYmLGhzBoRcvgCalJGiBlCBZcAABM+UiIVxVoQQhDlT4gideEvBAA)

As you might have noticed, I have slightly updated `Types` type.

If you hover your mouse on `return value` in `getObjectValue1_Error` you will see this error:

```
Type '{ n: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ n: number; } & { s: string; }'
```

Instead of `never` you have received an intersection. Why?

> Multiple candidates for the same type variable in contra-variant positions causes an intersection type to be inferred.

Hence, you have received `never` because `string & number = never`.

**How to fix original getObjectValue ?**

**Tip:**
If you want to use some object in your function body, try to always pass him as an argument. It helps TS to infer all types you need.

So instead of just using `objects` inside `getObjectValue`  - curry it.

```js
type Types = {
    num: number
    str: string
}

// get a union of all values
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]
{
    // string | number
    type Test = Values<Types>
}

// take a union and makes na intersection - merges it
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
) => void
    ? I
    : never;

type AllowedStates<T> = {
    [Prop in keyof T]: Record<Prop, { value: T[Prop] }>
}
{
    // collection of all allowed states with extra hight level property
    type Test = AllowedStates<Types>
}

type Objects<T> = UnionToIntersection<Values<AllowedStates<T>>>
{
    // allowed state
    type Test = Objects<Types>
}

// Overloading for curried function ->    <K extends keyof Obj>(key: K) =>obj[key].value
type Overloading<Obj extends Record<string, { value: unknown }>> =
    & (<K extends keyof Obj>(key: K) => Obj[K]['value'])

export const withObj = <
    T extends Types,
    Obj extends Objects<T> & Record<string, { value: Values<Types> }>,
    >(obj: Obj):
    Overloading<Obj> => <K extends keyof Obj>(key: K) =>
        obj[key].value

const getObjectValue = withObj({
    num: {
        value: 7
    },
    str: {
        value: "hi"
    }
})

const result1 = getObjectValue('str') // string
const result2 = getObjectValue('num') // number
```

Now, ts is able to infer all the type you need.